# Blackberry Development using NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have gone through with the tutorial documents for blackberry development.

At every place they have showed the features with eclipse plugins.

So, I would like to know that which are the tools I need to download If I want to start development using NetBeans 6.8 (or 6.5) ? And what is the procedure to do so ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the Eclipse plugin. Its supported from RIM and it has a large enough community base for troubleshooting.

Comment: hmm.. this is like nirmal asking how do i make coffee with sugar and you replying well tea's really good with sugar and alot of people drink it.

Comment: Apparently tea is **a lot** better than coffee.

Answer (score 2):

One guy called Jonathan Fisher did come up with a solution, but his page disappeared off the web a while ago. But I managed to find it using the Wayback machine to get the [archived webpage](http://web.archive.org/web/20080326234549/http://jonathanhfisher.co.uk/newsitems/blackberrynetbeansdev/index.htm).

Basically you need to first install the Blackberry JDE (which is Eclipse based), then in Netbeans Mobility settings go to **Manage Emulators** and do **Add Plaform** in the platforms manager to add a custom platform that points to your Blackberry JDE directory, and remove all the automatically added jars except for net_rim_api.jar

Next, when you start a MIDP project, select your new custom Blackberry platform as your emulator in the project settings. You will also need to add some custom build settings to build.xml, plus a Blackberry .alx application loader file to the project. It's a bit long-winded, so best to follow the instructions as per the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plugins that are available for BlackBerry development on Netbeans. But, you can do so, if

1. you are willing to give up the on device debugging that you can get with Eclipse plugin.
2. And are willing and know how to install BlackBerry JDE in Netbeans.

The advantage here is Netbeans has a lot more sophisticated preprocessor support, whereas BlackBerry plugin in Eclipse has rudimentary support for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a short article on this on my blog [link text](http://m-shaheen.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-configure-netbeans-for.html)

, it tells you how to confguire Netbeans for BB development.
this is only supporting J2ME not cldc .